# Rabbitmq's management plugin's aliveness-test timing out for all cluster nodes

Tags: rabbitmq

I was doing POC for aliveness-test and saw a strange scenario, where it started timing out for all the cluster nodes. I am planning to use application level health check in HAProxy using this aliveness-test API. But this scenario scared me as HAProxy started showing all the cluster nodes as DOWN when aliveness-test was timing out for all the cluster nodes But the rabbitmq server port was connectable during that time. As per the documentation, rabbitmq management tool (which listens to port 15672) can be assumed connectable while server (which listens at port 5672) is up and running.

When I was restarting rabbit nodes, it was going in the same state.

It resumed and started returning response code 200 when I killed rabbitmq processes in all the hosts using kill -9  and started the app gracefully.

how this can be avoided?

Putting some error logs from one of the node------

```
=INFO REPORT==== 7-Jul-2017::16:05:18 ===
Mirrored queue 'aliveness-test' in vhost '/': Slave <rabbit@pgperf-rabbitmq2.1.26928.0> saw deaths of mirrors <rabbit@pgperf-rabbitmq1.1.18235.0>

=WARNING REPORT==== 7-Jul-2017::16:05:18 ===
Mnesia('rabbit@pgperf-rabbitmq2'): ** WARNING ** Mnesia is overloaded: {dump_log,write_threshold}

=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Jul-2017::16:05:18 ===
** Generic server <0.27470.0> terminating
** Last message in was {'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.24.29729>,process,<7887.11927.0>,
                               noproc}
** When Server state == {state,
                            {20,<0.27470.0>},
                            {{17,<7888.18916.0>},#Ref<0.0.24.29728>},
                            {{10,<7887.11927.0>},#Ref<0.0.24.29729>},
                            {resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"aliveness-test">>},
                            rabbit_mirror_queue_slave,
                            {21,
                             [{{10,<7887.11927.0>},
                               {view_member,
                                   {10,<7887.11927.0>},
                                   [],
                                   {20,<0.27470.0>},
                                   {14,<7888.18825.0>}}},
                              {{12,<0.26929.0>},
                               {view_member,
                                   {12,<0.26929.0>},
                                   [],
                                   {14,<7888.18825.0>},
                                   {17,<7888.18916.0>}}},
                              {{14,<7888.18825.0>},
                               {view_member,
                                   {14,<7888.18825.0>},
                                   [],
                                   {10,<7887.11927.0>},
                                   {12,<0.26929.0>}}},
                              {{17,<7888.18916.0>},
                               {view_member,
                                   {17,<7888.18916.0>},
                                   [],
                                   {12,<0.26929.0>},
                                   {20,<0.27470.0>}}},
                              {{20,<0.27470.0>},
                               {view_member,
                                   {20,<0.27470.0>},
                                   [],
                                   {17,<7888.18916.0>},
                                   {10,<7887.11927.0>}}}]},
                            -1,
                            [{{10,<7887.11927.0>},{member,{[],[]},1,1}},
                             {{12,<0.26929.0>},
                              {member,{[{1,process_death}],[]},1,-1}},
                             {{14,<7888.18825.0>},{member,{[],[]},0,0}},
                             {{17,<7888.18916.0>},{member,{[],[]},-1,-1}},
                             {{20,<0.27470.0>},{member,{[],[]},-1,-1}}],
                            [<0.27469.0>],
                            {[],[]},
                            [],0,undefined,
                            #Fun<rabbit_misc.execute_mnesia_transaction.1>,
                            false}
** Reason for termination ==
** {bad_return_value,
       {error,
           {function_clause,
               [{gm,check_membership,
                    [{20,<0.27470.0>},{error,not_found}],
                    [{file,"src/gm.erl"},{line,1590}]},
                {gm,'-record_dead_member_in_group/5-fun-1-',4,
                    [{file,"src/gm.erl"},{line,1132}]},
                {mnesia_tm,apply_fun,3,[{file,"mnesia_tm.erl"},{line,833}]},
                {mnesia_tm,execute_transaction,5,
                    [{file,"mnesia_tm.erl"},{line,808}]},
                {rabbit_misc,'-execute_mnesia_transaction/1-fun-0-',1,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,537}]},
                {worker_pool_worker,'-run/2-fun-0-',3,
                    [{file,"src/worker_pool_worker.erl"},{line,77}]}]}}}

=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Jul-2017::16:05:18 ===
** Generic server <0.27469.0> terminating
** Last message in was {'EXIT',<0.27470.0>,
                        {bad_return_value,
                         {error,
                          {function_clause,
                           [{gm,check_membership,
                             [{20,<0.27470.0>},{error,not_found}],
                             [{file,"src/gm.erl"},{line,1590}]},
                            {gm,'-record_dead_member_in_group/5-fun-1-',4,
                             [{file,"src/gm.erl"},{line,1132}]},
                            {mnesia_tm,apply_fun,3,
                             [{file,"mnesia_tm.erl"},{line,833}]},
                            {mnesia_tm,execute_transaction,5,
                             [{file,"mnesia_tm.erl"},{line,808}]},
                            {rabbit_misc,
                             '-execute_mnesia_transaction/1-fun-0-',1,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,537}]},
                            {worker_pool_worker,'-run/2-fun-0-',3,
                             [{file,"src/worker_pool_worker.erl"},
                              {line,77}]}]}}}}
** When Server state == {state,
                         {amqqueue,
                          {resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"aliveness-test">>},
                          false,false,none,[],<7888.18913.0>,
                          [<7887.11753.0>],
                          [<7887.11753.0>],
                          ['rabbit@pgpdr-rabbitmq2'],
                          [{vhost,<<"/">>},
                           {name,<<"ha-all">>},
                           {pattern,<<>>},
                           {'apply-to',<<"all">>},
                           {definition,
                            [{<<"ha-mode">>,<<"all">>},
                             {<<"ha-sync-mode">>,<<"automatic">>}]},
                           {priority,0}],
                          [{<7888.18916.0>,<7888.18913.0>},
                           {<7887.11774.0>,<7887.11753.0>}],
                          [],live},
                         <0.27470.0>,rabbit_priority_queue,
                         {passthrough,rabbit_variable_queue,
                          {vqstate,
                           {0,{[],[]}},
                           {0,{[],[]}},
                           {delta,undefined,0,undefined},
                           {0,{[],[]}},
                           {0,{[],[]}},
                           0,
                           {0,nil},
                           {0,nil},
                           {0,nil},
                           {qistate,
                            "/paytm/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@pgperf-rabbitmq2/queues/1EZ1LHRKWKS0CPF59OD5ZBSYL",
                            {{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                              {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                               []},
                              {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                []}}},
                             []},
                            undefined,0,32768,
                            #Fun<rabbit_variable_queue.2.95522769>,
                            #Fun<rabbit_variable_queue.3.95522769>,
                            {0,nil},
                            {0,nil},
                            [],[]},
                           {undefined,
                            {client_msstate,msg_store_transient,
                             <<190,153,122,22,186,127,25,5,168,81,229,140,5,
                               142,73,73>>,
                             {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                              {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                               []},
                              {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                []}}},
                             {state,438349,
                              "/paytm/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@pgperf-rabbitmq2/msg_store_transient"},
                             rabbit_msg_store_ets_index,
                             "/paytm/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@pgperf-rabbitmq2/msg_store_transient",
                             <0.370.0>,442446,434242,446543,450640,
                             {2000,500}}},
                           false,0,4096,0,0,0,0,0,infinity,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                           {rates,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-576459879667187727},
                           {0,nil},
                           {0,nil},
                           {0,nil},
                           {0,nil},
                           0,0,0,0,2048,default}},
                         undefined,undefined,
                         {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                          {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
                          {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},
                         {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                          {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
                          {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},
                         {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                          {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
                          {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},
                         {state,
                          {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                           {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
                           {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                             []}}},
                          delegate},
                         undefined}
** Reason for termination ==
** {bad_return_value,
       {error,
           {function_clause,
               [{gm,check_membership,
                    [{20,<0.27470.0>},{error,not_found}],
                    [{file,"src/gm.erl"},{line,1590}]},
                {gm,'-record_dead_member_in_group/5-fun-1-',4,
                    [{file,"src/gm.erl"},{line,1132}]},
                {mnesia_tm,apply_fun,3,[{file,"mnesia_tm.erl"},{line,833}]},
                {mnesia_tm,execute_transaction,5,
                    [{file,"mnesia_tm.erl"},{line,808}]},
                {rabbit_misc,'-execute_mnesia_transaction/1-fun-0-',1,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,537}]},
                {worker_pool_worker,'-run/2-fun-0-',3,
                    [{file,"src/worker_pool_worker.erl"},{line,77}]}]}}}

=WARNING REPORT==== 7-Jul-2017::16:05:18 ===
Mnesia('rabbit@pgperf-rabbitmq2'): ** WARNING ** Mnesia is overloaded: {dump_log,write_threshold}

=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Jul-2017::16:47:39 ===
Channel error on connection <0.27776.0> (<rabbit@pgperf-rabbitmq2.1.27776.0>, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'), channel 1:
operation basic.get caused a channel exception not_found: "failed to perform operation on queue 'aliveness-test' in vhost '/' due to timeout"

=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Jul-2017::16:47:39 ===
webmachine error: path="/api/aliveness-test/%2F"
"Not Found"

=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Jul-2017::16:47:39 ===
Channel error on connection <0.10847.1> (<rabbit@pgperf-rabbitmq2.1.10847.1>, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'), channel 1:
operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found: "failed to perform operation on queue 'aliveness-test' in vhost '/' due to timeout"

=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Jul-2017::16:47:39 ===
Channel error on connection <0.151.1> (<rabbit@pgperf-rabbitmq2.1.151.1>, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'), channel 1:
operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found: "failed to perform operation on queue 'aliveness-test' in vhost '/' due to timeout"
```